# How do I display only selected items in a ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm creating a stacked bar plot of relative abundance data, but I only want to display the ten most abundant organisms in the legend. How do I do this? I have no idea where to begin and haven't found any answers online.

Here's the plot with a full legend:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) in the comments, the answer is to add a list of selected items to the `breaks=` argument in `scale_fill_manual()`

> scale_fill_manual(breaks=list,values=colpal)