# Select ggplot legend items and preserve palette colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

There are similar question answered here, but not for my particular issue.

Let's have a data frame and ggplot bar:

```
d <- data.frame(
  letters = LETTERS[1:10],
  numbers = 11:20
)

ggplot(d, aes(x = letters, y = numbers, fill = letters)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

I need to show only A and J items in legend. I can use this code, but the gradient palette is broken completely and I don't know how to put it back.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = letters, y = numbers, fill = letters)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("A", "J"), values = d$letters)
```

Do you know it please?

Similiar questions:

- [Remove selected labels (factors) from legend in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801950/remove-selected-labels-factors-from-legend-in-ggplot2)
- [How do I display only selected items in a ggplot2 legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076911/how-do-i-display-only-selected-items-in-a-ggplot2-legend)

Comment: Here is a question which answers your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697211/select-ggplot-legend-items-and-preserve-palette-colors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify `scale_fill_discrete` your code should therefore look like this:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = letters, y = numbers, fill = letters)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("A", "J"))
```

[image: Plot]